# Mute led does not work HP Pavilion 15

Tags: mute

I have HP Pavilion Laptop 15-eg0016nw (2Q1C0EA) and the mute led (on F5 key) doesn't work/light on Ubuntu 21.10 / kernel 5.13.0-20-generic (Realtek ALC287 audio codec).

What can I do to make this work? The caps lock LED works on Ubuntu.

Thanks!

Comment: Silly question maybe - but does it actually mute but the led doesn’t light, or does the key do nothing?

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

When I press the F5 key, the sound is muted, but the LED informing about it does not turn on (the LED works properly on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

use this : $sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x500 0x0b && sudo hda-verb /dev/snd/hwC1D0 0x20 0x400 0x08

Comment: How does the command work?